# Can SparkSession.catalog.clearCache() delete data from hdfs?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-spark-2.3

I am experiencing some data deletion issue since we have migrated from CDH to HDP (spark 2.2 to 2.3). The tables are being read from an hdfs location and after a certain time running spark job that reads and processes those tables, it throws **table not found exception** and when we check that location all the records are vanished. In my spark(Java) code I see before that table is read, clearCache() is called. Can it delete those files? If yes, how do I fix it?

Comment: `clearCache` _Removes all cached tables **from the in-memory cache**._ https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Catalog.html#clearCache--

Comment: Yes, I have checked this , but would that mean it removes files/table records from hdfs? I don't understand what it means by removing from in-memory cache. @mazaneicha

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/CacheManager.scala#L59) -
Spark has their own implementation of caching user data and they never delete the same while managing this cache via CacheManager. Have alook